# omniORBpy terminating the server

Tags: python, corba

I'm working on python client-server application that uses omniORBpy and I'm trying to figure out how to correctly terminate the server.

I have this method to do so:

```
def shutdown(self):
    print "---------------------------------------"
    print "shutdown"
    orb.shutdown(False)
    quit()
```

But when I send a message from client that calls above mentioned function a get this error:

```
---------------------------------------
shutdown
omniORB: Caught an unexpected Python exception during up-call.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'omni_thread_fatal'
Aborted
```

Does anybody know what do I have to do to end server correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot shutdown the server (even not in a oneway call). You have to change a "flag" so that it is checked frequently. If it is set, shutdown the server.

E.g., in pseudocode:

```
def shutdown():
  self.shutdown = True

def run():
  while not self.shutdown:
     workloop()
```

Or something like this. In other words; don't kill the server in a remote call.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make the shutdown method an oneway method in IDL?

Comment: Yes, I did: oneway void shutdownDFS();